# Use the ANOVA procedures to find the p-value

Tags: statistics

You take a random sample of 100 golfers, each of whom hits Brand A once. You then take a second (separate) random sample of 100 golfers, each of whom hits Brand B once. The second sample is independent of the first. Define X as the distance for Brand A and Y as the distance for Brand B. For the two independent samples, Σ_i x_i = 20,000 yards, Σ_j y_j = 19,500 yards, Σ_i x_i^2 = 4,090,000 yards squared, Σ_j y_j^2 = 3,892,500 yards squared. Use the ANOVA procedures to find the F statistic and p-value.

I know the procedures to find the F statistics but how do you do it with the given information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you only have two groups A and B, I'm wondering why you
aren't using a t test instead of an ANOVA.

From the information given
$$\bar X = \left(\sum_i X_i\right)/100 = 20,000/100 = 200.$$

Also,
$$S_X^2 = \left(\sum_i X_i^2 - n\bar X^2\right)/(n-1)
= [4,090,000 - 100(200^2)]/99.$$

You can find $\bar Y$ and $S_Y^2$ similarly. Then you
are ready to compute either the T-statistic or the F-statistic.
(The F-statistic would be the square of the pooled T-statistic.)

With a pooled t test you'll have $DF = 100 + 100 - 2 = 198,$
which you probably won't find in your t-table because it's
so large. The T-statistic is essentially standard normal.

You should be able to take it from there. If not, please leave
a comment or revise your question with the required additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the ANOVA tool you're using, it's difficult to advise. You have the sums and sums-of-squares for each treatment, so you can calculate the total variation (*v*) and the "between" variation due to treatment (*v_b*) so you should have all you need.